# Excel VBA: The leading zero is missing when use as email address

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to draft a new email with Excel VBA and add the email address "00000@mycompany.com" in the cc list, while "00000" is the 5 digits staff number. The user should fill in their staff number in the form range "T5", "V5", or "X5".

However, if their staff number starts with zero, the leading zero will be missing in the email address.

For example, the number they filled is "01234", but the email address in the draft email will be "1234@mycompany.com"

I have tried

```
.text
.numberformat="@" and 
.numberformat="00000"
```

but they are not working.

Could anyone help me with this? thanks a lot!

```
Private Sub sendmail_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")

    Dim OA As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    Dim filepath As String
    Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim folder
    Set folder = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)

    With msg
    .display
    End With
    signature = msg.Body

    Dim var_cc As String
    var_cc = ""

    With msg
    .To = "abc@mycompany.com"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(sh.Range("T5")) = True Then
    var_cc = var_cc & sh.Range("T5").NumberFormat = "@" & "@mycompany.com;"
    Else
    End If
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(sh.Range("V5")) = True Then
    var_cc = var_cc & sh.Range("V5").Value & "@mycompany.com;;"
    Else
    End If
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(sh.Range("X5")) = True Then
    var_cc = var_cc & sh.Range("X5").Value & "@mycompany.com;;"
    Else
    End If
    .cc = var_cc
    .Subject = sh.Range("G5").Value & " " & sh.Range("D5").Value & " " & sh.Range("A5").Value & " " & sh.Range("E3").Value & " / " & 
    sh.Range("E2").Value
    .Body = "Dear All," & vbNewLine & _
    "Please find attached missing info. Thank you." & _
     vbNewLine & signature
     .importance = 2
     .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

    End With


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```vb
var_cc = var_cc & Format(sh.Range("T5").Value, "00000") & "@mycompany.com;"
```

instead of

```vb
var_cc = var_cc & sh.Range("T5").NumberFormat = "@" & "@mycompany.com;"
```